# "Хорошее дело "браком" не назовут"

Tags: этимология, омонимы

Откуда пошло современное слово "брак" в значении "свадьба"? И для слова "брак" в значении "недоделка", "плохо сделанная работа" оно является омонимом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово *БРАК* «супружество» имеет славянское происхожение (заимствовано в русский язык из старославянского). Ст.-сл. бракъ «женитьба, супружество» образовано с пом. суф. -к-ъ (как знак) от глаг. бьрати > брать, беру. Связь слова брак с этим глаг. подтверждается выражением *брать замуж*, диалектное *браться* «жениться», укр. *побралися* «женились». Глаг. *бьрати*, первонач. «нести», в применении к женитьбе значит «схватить, похитить»: основу брака у древних славян составляло похищение девушки из другого рода, племени.

Слово *БРАК* «изъян», «недоброкачественность» (товара) заимствовано из немецкого языка в Петровскую эпоху. Нем. *Brack* «брак, недостаток, порок» происходит от *brechen* «ломать», «разбивать» и значит по этимол. «поломка» («лом»), «повреждение» > «изделие с изъяном» > «недоброкачественный товар».

Таким образом, имеем два омонима разного происхождения (Цыганенко Г.П. Этимологический словарь русского языка).